# dense_Rank() Function in sql server should start from 1 and not from 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to give rank for the students based on their marks in sql server. If student get 0 marks then rank should be 0 or -. but when i use dense_rank() function the order of rank starts from 0 and not from 1. Can any one help me with sample query for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If marks are 1, 0 and 3 what should be the ranks?

Comment: then 3 marks rank is 1,1 marks rank is 2 and 0 mark rank is 0

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

From [DENSE_RANK (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> The rank of a row is one plus the number of distinct ranks that come
>   before the row in question.

Which would imply that the first row would be 0+1=>1, and not 0 as you stated.

This can also be seen from

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11464)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
select 
    (case when marks=0 then 0 else DENSE_RANK() over (order by marks desc) end) RNK, 
    marks,
    student
from(
    select 5 as marks, 'a' student union
    select 5 as marks, 'b' student union
    select 0 as marks, 'c' student union
    select 1 as marks, 'd' student union
    select 1 as marks, 'e' student union
    select 3 as marks, 'f' student 
)x
--order by RNK --Add order by clause if 0th rank to come first.
```

Comment: In this example rank with 0 comes first, but rank 0 students should be last

Comment: @Jaswanth . . . Your question explicitly says "If student get 0 marks then rank should be 0 or -".  This answer appears to be coorect.

Comment: Hi This is the same i need, but the student with rank 0 comes first but he should be last for ex:student 'c' should be shown last.

Comment: Just remove the order by clause and check.